# node.js response with a csv file ? (without express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, d3.js

I'm running a node.js server locally to build a D3.js chart. I have a csv file and index.html in the same folder. I can load my index.html file using the following line of code :

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
        if( request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/' ){
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            //Open file as readable stream, pipe stream to response object
            fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
        }else{
            send404Response(response);
        }

    }
```

Can I use the same code "template" to build a get response with my csv file ? Can I do this without express ?

Thanks !

edit : here is the solution :

```
function onRequest(request, response) {
    if( request.method == 'GET' && request.url === '/data.tsv' )

    fs.readFile('./data.tsv', function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/tsv", "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=data.tsv"});
    response.end(buffer.toString());
  });


   else if( request.method == 'GET' && request.url === '/' ){
       response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
       //Open file as readable stream, pipe stream to response object
       fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);
   }else{
       send404Response(response);
   }

}
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? You should use express, with a static file serving middleware.  You can also just use a module like `st` directly.

Comment: Yes, you can detect request for CSV file by checking `request.url` and server correct file according to that value.

Comment: Thanks guys. Not trying to reinventing the wheel but trying to understand. but yeah I just edit my post I've found a solution ! :)